# Adding a number with zero's

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

When i add a the number with zeros means, it is showing exact result without zero's

For Example

```
Dim a, b, c as int32

a = 001
b = 5
c = a + b

a = 009
b = 13
c = a + b
```

Showing output as 6 instead of 006, 22  instead of 022

Expected output

```
006
022
```

How to do this.

Need vb.net code help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store a number as a string if you want to store the exact number of zeros. Then addition won't work though.

If you just want to *display* the number with 3 digits, you can store it as an integer and format the result when you print it.

```
c.ToString("D3")
```

Answer (score 0):

zero is nothing.. If you do a regular mathematical calculation of 001 + 5 the result is still 6. I would suggest you check out string padding.